# Is there a way to re-write a counter for-loop as a lapply/sapply/map function without using the " <<- " operator?

Tags: r

Is there a way to re-write the counter for-loop below using lapply/map (or sapply), **but** without using the "<<-" assignment operator?

I have a list of data frames (`list_of_dfs`) from which I need to determine the total number of rows contained in the entire list of data frames. The code below works fine, but I want to know if I can get away without using a for-loop and not using the scoping assignment operator "<<-" to count the total number of rows.

Counter for-loop:

```r
count <- 0
for(df in list_of_dfs){
    count <- count + nrow(df)
}
```

The purrr::map function below does the trick, but I would like to avoid the "<<-" operator. purrr::walk, lapply and sapply gets to the same result.

```r
count <- 0
map(list_of_dfs, function(x){
    count <<- count + nrow(x)
})
```

It just seems sloppy...like some backyard workaround. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `count <- sum(sapply(list_of_dfs, FUN=nrow))`

Comment: Generally no - unless you use global assignment there is no way for one iteration of an `*apply` loop to have information about previous iterations. For this simple example, as others show there are better ways. In a more complex case, I'd recommend using a `for` loop instead of `*apply`.

Answer (score 3):

We an use `sum`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_int(list_of_dfs, nrow) %>%
     sum
```

---

Or with `sapply`

```
sum(sapply(list_of_dfs, nrow))
```